# Print three columns vertically separated by space(s)

Tags: code-golf, string

## Task

- Take input string separated by space.
- Sort the words alphabetically.
- Print them out vertically in 3 columns separated by space(s).

## Challenge

- All three column's heights should be as evenly weighted as possible.
- All three column's should be left aligned.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

## Example

If the input is:

```
"cat caterpillar pie frog elephant pizza",
```

The output should be:

```
cat         elephant pie
caterpillar frog     pizza
```

Please beware of cases, if input is:

```
"a b c d e f g"
```

Should be printed as:

```
a c e
b d f
    g

# or

a d f
b e g
c

# and not

a d g
b e
c f
```

Comment: Also, I would recommend you remove the strict I/O requirement; that is, take input as a list of strings in any form (as answerer wants) and as a program or a function taking the list.

Comment: Is it acceptable to output [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk0Pdy4qNnb///@/UnJiiQIQpxYVZObkJBYpFGSmKqQV5acrpOakFmQk5pUARaqqEpUA) for the first example?

Comment: @Satendra Don't worry about the "put on hold as off-topic...", when/if the question is sufficiently good it will be reopened. | You can consider using the sandbox.

Comment: Please consider using the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) in the future to get feedback on your challenges before posting them to the main site.

Comment: Probably trivial, but you can clarify the `as evenly weighted as possible` part as `minimize the difference between the maximum height and the minimum height`, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Satendra Nice first challenge. If the columns must be separated by a single space at the narrowest gap, you should state so.

Comment: What characters can occur in the input?

Comment: @Zgarb only alphabets, no special character

Comment: How is the first "should be printed" as acceptable? Since it looks right aligned to me.

Comment: @Matt Each *word* should be left-aligned, the *table* itself can be right-aligned.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>24</s> 17 bytes

```
TmoTT' §CȯmLTC3Ow
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyQ3PyREXeHQcucT63N9QpyN/cv///@vlKKQlKSQrJCYqJCamqqQppCukJGhkKWQqZCdrZCTo5CrBAA)

### Explanation

This was a surprisingly tricky challenge, as Husk currently lacks a builtin for breaking a list into a given number of parts.

```
TmoTT' §CȯmLTC3Ow  Implicit input, say s="bbb a cc ddd e"
                w  Split at spaces: x=["bbb","a","cc","ddd","e"]
             C3    Cut into slices of length 3: [["bbb","a","cc"],["ddd","e"]]
            T      Transpose: [["bbb","ddd"],["a","e"],["cc"]]
         ȯmL       Map length: [2,2,1]
                   These are the correct lengths of the columns.
       §C      O   Sort x and split into these lengths: [["a","bbb"],["cc","ddd"],["e"]]
                   These are the columns of the correct output, without padding.
 mo                For each column,
    T'             transpose and pad with spaces: [["ab"," b"," b"],["cd","cd"," d"],["e"]]
   T               then transpose back: [["a  ","bbb"],["cc ","ddd"],["e"]]
T                  Transpose the whole list: [["a  ","cc ","e"],["bbb","ddd"]]
                   Implicitly join each row by spaces,
                   join the resulting strings by newlines and print.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Ṣœs3ZG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkVHJxcbR7n///8/Wj05sURdRwFEpRYVZObkJBaBuAWZqSAqrSg/HUSn5qQWZCTmlUCkqqoS1WMB)

Comment: @DLosc It's actually been tested with the `a b c d e f g` case too, and I did other extensive tests because I had that feeling first too. Oh, and its shortness comes from the `G` (Format as **G**rid.) builtin.

Comment: Ah, there's a builtin. (Why am I surprised?) That explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 148 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to ovs.*

```python
l=sorted(input().split())
n=-~len(l)//3
f=lambda l:[i.ljust(max(map(len,l)))for i in l+['']]
for i in zip(f(l[:n]),f(l[n:n*2]),f(l[n*2:])):print(*i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYoxDoJAEEV7TjGdM4iQQLcJJyFbLMLKmGHYwJKohVdfsdDi5b/8vPCM06JNStJuyxrHAVnDHpHKLQgfS5m2l7eMikJV1WS@FTf3gwMxHZdy37eIs3scBDyqQojILyswsIKcu9PJ2ux/vDigR@mMWiq@okbz@ud5bSyRCStrxJwpJQc9XGGAETzcYPoA)

<s>Workin' on it.</s> *Everything* I've tried makes the output lopsided...

Comment: [148 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYoxDoJAEEV7TjGdM4iQQLcJJyFbLMLKmGHYwJKohVdfsdDi5b/8vPCM06JNStJuyxrHAVnDHpHKLQgfS5m2l7eMikJV1WS@FTf3gwMxHZdy37eIs3scBDyqQojILyswsIKcu9PJ2ux/vDigR@mMWiq@okbz@ud5bSyRCStrxJwpJQc9XGGAETzcYPoA) using python 3.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 115 bytes

```
Grid[Transpose@PadRight@TakeList[#,Last@IntegerPartitions[Tr[1^#],3]]&@Sort@StringSplit@#/. 0->"",Alignment->Left]&
```

try it on [wolfram sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)

paste the following code and press shift+enter

```
Grid[Transpose@PadRight@TakeList[#,Last@IntegerPartitions[Tr[1^#],3]]&@Sort@StringSplit@#/. 0->"",Alignment->Left]&["cat caterpillar pie frog elephant pizza"]
```

Comment: @HalvardHummel fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 134 + 1 (`-a`) = 135 bytes

```perl
$.=(sort{$b=~y///c-length$a}(@F=sort@F))[0]=~y///c;@a=splice@F,0,@F/3;@b=splice@F,0,@F/2;printf"%-$.s "x3 .$/,shift@a,shift@b,$_ for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYnRCsIgFEB/5TIMNnBzFD0NwSd/IiLuRDdBpqgPtahPzxbsqYfDgXOCju5cCul4nXzMTzLy94MxplqnlynPBF@1kPz3hGyaS3/d/yCQp@Cs0kLSngrJToMY/9JxCNEu2VSHlnQJqvsJOsJomq3JAnePlNzA@ChkKQozbOgYrHMYIVgNJvoJtNNhxiVvZV0RENTHh2z9kkqLXw)

Comment: What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
#{.B3äζ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fuVrPyfjwknPbDu3@/z9RIUkhWSFFIVUhTSEdAA)

---

```
#        | Split on spaces.
 {       | Sort aphabetically.
  .B     | Pad to max string length.
    3ä   | Split into columns.
      ζ  | Transpose.
       » | Print with newlines.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript <strike>181</strike> 175 bytes

```js
f=a=>(a=a.split` `).sort().map(c=>(t[y]=[...t[y]||[],c],M[x]>(l=c.length)?0:M[x]=l,a[++y*3+x]?y:y=x++*0),M=[t=[x=y=0]])&&t.map(x=>x.map((c,y)=>c.padEnd(M[y])).join` `).join`
`

console.log(f("cat caterpillar pie frog elephant pizza"))
console.log("-------------------")
console.log(f("cat caterpillar pie frog frog123123 pizza"))
console.log("-------------------")
console.log(f("a b c d e f g"))
console.log("-------------------")
console.log(f("a b c d e f"))
console.log("-------------------")
console.log(f("a b c d e"))
console.log("-------------------")
console.log(f("a b c d"))

/*
f=a=>(a=a.split` `).sort().map(c=>((t[y] =t[y]||[])[x]=c,M[x]>(l=c.length)?0:M[x]=l,++y*3+x<a.length?0:y=x++*0),M=[t=[x=y=0]])&&t.map(x=>x.map((c,y)=>c.padEnd(M[y])).join` `).join`\n`

f=a=>(a=a.split` `).sort().map(c=>(t[y]=[...t[y]||[],c],M[x]>(l=c.length)?0:M[x]=l,++y*3+x<a.length?0:y=x++*0),M=[t=[x=y=0]])&&t.map(x=>x.map((c,y)=>c.padEnd(M[y])).join` `).join`\n`

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 73 bytes

```
,.@(' ',"1[:>|:)@((](s,(s=.]{.1:),(1:{.~[-2*]))([:<.0.5+%&3))@#];.1])@/:~
```

I can explain this mess later if someone is interested.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9JT8MwEIXv/RVWETiB1DQgLg5FYd/3nSoHN520pk4cOUkFLfSvh3iEennz5Pfm0/izTgrSY6RLOOnWHgsdSqjX9vt874e7oeNETuE5RY9Fc@Zz13N8PmeLfmdrPXJdp893WZftbKyubbtuuBIFzI/ccJMvarfVZoQmPU6JR345SYoWxGNNEkJjUdIAB5hcKiUMJSSguQScidEjNKAgH4us/E9nM2EdobkoSkGXOGFhAyRaGVoBK4mVBrVs7quGZx@fM5lok9KAHhgx1fbpCFSJ2etYFhP4tva42bPzRH@VRuPRp1oh9kyXoKw5z4YS9z4qVTXAi0pJwOqlVLh9JVMsXMsJnnWjp5AOwFh/W8QCzZ3IsXRfwQDwHw86Bdx/lGAMhodjYRq6tU8iG2H6IuNSI@KtYwSe/S6yCQCt6z8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```
≔⪪θ ηＦη«⊞υ⌊η≔⟦⟧ηＦ⪪θ ¿¬№υκ⊞ηκ»ＦＥ³✂υ÷×ιＬυ³÷×⊕ιＬυ³Ｉ1«Ｐ⪫ι¶¿ιＭ⊕⌈ＥιＬκ→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZAxT8MwEIXn5lecMp2lMKBudEJlKSIIUTZgsNJLfMKxjXOJUBG/PdgpEqo6ePD53Xvfc2N0bLy283w7DNw53AfLgp8VlFCqCozaFK2PgEbBd7F6GgeDYwU1O@7HPk3T@@pv9fX9pF@lhXMfBdwCPnrBrR@dZIcPlaaLncmXTfFzyql1wHUFe8sNZd3OyR1PfCB84Z4G5AoeyHWSMFTiW6tLyc41kXpyQgdkdanf6kGwvE5YailVj1Y4RE5g955djijfXLlUy9ysoPYTnfnW@mv5gIz7j5RLpYCbZ@6M5E7z3GiBdCgGtlZHCEzQRt8BWQpGO0mT41EX89VkfwE) Link is to verbose version of code. Save 2 bytes if I don't have to handle the case of fewer than 3 words. There's probably a sorting "eval" I should be using... Explanation:

```
≔⪪θ η
```

Split the input on spaces.

```
Ｆη«⊞υ⌊η≔⟦⟧ηＦ⪪θ ¿¬№υκ⊞ηκ»
```

Sort the array.

```
ＦＥ³✂υ÷×ιＬυ³÷×⊕ιＬυ³Ｉ1«
```

Loop over three approximately equal slices of the array. (`Ｉ1` should really be `¦¹`.)

```
Ｐ⪫ι¶
```

Join the slice with newlines and print it without moving the cursor.

```
¿ιＭ⊕⌈ＥιＬκ→
```

If the slice is not empty then move right by one more than the length of the longest word in the slice.

Answer (score 0):

## 358 bytes of minified JS:

```
function f(b){let d=[,,,],e=b.split(" ").sort(),g=[],h=[];for(var j in e){var k=Math.min(2,Math.floor(j/Math.floor(e.length/3)));d[k]||(d[k]=[],g[k]=e[j].length),d[k].push(e[j]),2==k&&h.push(""),g[k]=Math.max(e[j].length,g[k])}for(var o in g)for(var p=0;p<g[o]+1;p++)for(var q in h)h[q]+=q>=d[o].length||p>=d[o][q].length?" ":d[o][q][p];return h.join("\n")}
```

```js
function f(b){let d=[,,,],e=b.split(" ").sort(),g=[],h=[];for(var j in e){var k=Math.min(2,Math.floor(j/Math.floor(e.length/3)));d[k]||(d[k]=[],g[k]=e[j].length),d[k].push(e[j]),2==k&&h.push(""),g[k]=Math.max(e[j].length,g[k])}for(var o in g)for(var p=0;p<g[o]+1;p++)for(var q in h)h[q]+=q>=d[o].length||p>=d[o][q].length?" ":d[o][q][p];return h.join("\n")}

console.log(f("cat caterpillar pie frog elephant pizza"));
console.log(f("a b c d e f g"));
```

Comment: @StephenLeppik np

Answer (score 0):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 92 + 1 = 93 bytes

+1 bytes for `-r` flag.

I haven’t golfed this at all, but it turned out to be a lot simpler than I expected.

```
s/$/ /
s/(\S+ ){1,3}/:&\n/g
:
s/:(\S)/\1:/g
/:\S/!bZ
s/: / &/g
t
:Z
s/: / :/g
t
s/ *:.*$//gm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nci9DsIgFAbQnae4Jk1j68@Xxu2@RreGBRWRBIEAU42vLqKJ4zlZX2vN6EAQGVs572h4TvvTC9xLDyO4NbcfICduBssZm/PybQL1rYrgP/nHDBr5OHaAedR6UYW00/GufKFoNbXQKVrnVKJbCqbluqp3iMUGn@shfQA)

Answer (score -1):

## Bourne shell, 172 bytes

```
F=/tmp/t
<$1 tr \  \\n|sort>$F
N=$(wc -w $F|awk '{print $1/3}')
for i in 0 1 2
do
awk 'NR%N==C {print}' N=$N C=$i $F 
done|awk '{printf "%s%s",$1,NR%3?" ":"\n"}'|column -t
```

It's more readable if formatted conventionally:

```
#! /bin/sh
F=/tmp/t
<$1 tr \  \\n | sort > $F
N=$(wc -w $F | awk '{print $1/3}')

for i in 0 1 2
do    
    awk -v N=$N -v C=$i 'NR % N == C {print}' $F 
done |
    awk '{printf "%s%s", $1, NR % 3 == 0? "\n" : " " }' | column -t
```

At the price of scanning the input once per column, it uses no arrays.  A more complex awk program could open 3 files (one for every Nth word), processing the input in one pass.  Then they could be concatenated and printed using the same last line.

The variable `N` isn't strictly needed, either; for the price of 4 bytes, we save scanning the input 3 more times.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Since this is a code golf challenge, we require all answers to make an effort to minimize the bytecount. You can do that in exactly the ways you've mentioned--removing whitespace, shortening invocations, etc. Once you've done that, add a header to your answer giving the language used and the number of bytes. And feel free to keep your current version underneath as an "ungolfed" solution.

Comment: Why aren't you making a scene about the 358 byte program, as well?